# remove pencil on uneven background

Tags: image, gimp, image-editing

I have this picture: http://fc07.deviantart.net/fs16/i/2007/124/a/f/Hand_and_Nib_Pen_Stock_2_by_austringer.jpg and would like to remove the pencil lines on the top of the paper with Gimp 2.8.4. how do I best go about this? I only have the jpg i.e. everything is on the same layer...

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want to write a plugin to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use "clone" tool to overwrite pencil lines with their neighbor white space, [this tutorial](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-the-Clone-Tool-in-Gimp) will help you.